# Firebase rule to ensure static values on doc creation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When I create a project from the client I want to ensure they haven't tampered with the `plan` and `limits`:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /projects/{projectId} {
      function hasRole(rsc, role) {
        return rsc.data.users[request.auth.uid].role == role;
      }

      function userExistsInProject(rsc) {
        return (request.auth.uid) in rsc.data.users;
      }

      function projectResource() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId));
      }

      function planIsStandard(rsc) {
        return rsc.data.plan == 'standard' && rsc.data.limits.nodes == 1;
      }

      allow create: if isSignedIn() && planIsStandard(resource);
      allow read: if isSignedIn() && userExistsInProject(resource);
      allow write: if isSignedIn() && hasRole(resource, 'owner');

      match /cluster/{clusterId} {
        allow create, write: if isSignedIn() && hasRole(projectResource(), 'owner');
        allow list, read: if isSignedIn() && userExistsInProject(projectResource());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `planIsStandard` function is not working. If I include either of the conditions within that it doesn't work with the following:

```js
await db.collection('projects').add({
  plan: 'standard',
  limits: {
    nodes: 1,
  },
  name,
  created: new Date(),
  owner: user.uid,
  users: {
    [user.uid]: true,
  },
});
```

If I remove the `projectIsStandard` check I can create the doc.

This seems like a normal rule I can't see what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the contents of an incoming document, you need to use [`request.resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource) instead of `resource`.  The latter only looks at the existing document, if one even exists.  `request.resource` looks at the new document, or the proposed changes to the it.

As such, your rules are only looking at existing documents in the database, which is never going to apply to newly created documents.